# I want to retrieve information from the Autodesk Cloud Construction files using API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to extract the information of my ACC files such as the file Number/name and add that into my third party application. I don't know how can i do it. a detailed step-by-step answer would be much appreciated. How can i access the API?

Thanks